# select distinct values from gae datastore and render html

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

This is my first app development. so please bear with me. I have an entity called Apple in my datastore from which i need to retrive the column Appname. I just need to retrieve the distinct appnames and render my simple html dropdown list.I just don't find a distinct command in the gql doc. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in the docs.  I think your query will look something like this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Appname FROM Apple
```

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference